# Prove that there is a subgroup $K$ : $k! | [H:K]$

Tags: group-theory

Consider a group $G$, and $H \in G$ - subgroup with $[G:H] = k$, then prove that there is exists normal subgroup $K$ in $H$ such that $k! | [G:K]$?

Actually I have no ideas. Any hints?

Comment: @DietrichBurde edited

Comment: Is it not the other way around, i.e., $[G:K]\mid k!$?